# Android studio adding admob in java class/findViewById error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

please help. I have Imageview slider app in android studio. And then I'll tried to add admob by adding code in one of Java classes after sync with Google Services.But it give mistakes

```
      C:\Users\AVERAIN\AndroidStudioProjects\southkorea\app\src\main\java\com\ave_rain\southkorea\FragmentOne.java
    Error:(24, 28) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Code In one of Java class called Fragment

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

 public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{
 private AdView mAdView;


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);    
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container,false);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);
        mAdView = (AdView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);  
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!Appreciated. Your genious. But i still didn't get a theory. What have you done?

Comment: When you want to use control of inside layout , you need to do like above

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

private AdView mAdView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);

    mAdView = (AdView)view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome Bro @KimVladislav

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Appreciated.It works too.